# Avoid using instanceof with entities

Tags: java, oop

Today I read [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/avoid-working-with-classes-and-reflection-where-po) about avoiding the use of instanceof.
This makes absolutely sense to me. I'm also aware of the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Lets say I have the following situation:

```
@Entity
public abstract class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer employeeId;

    private String name;

}



@Entity
public class FullTimeEmployee extends Employee {

    protected Integer salary;

    public Integer getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Integer salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
@Entity
public class PartTimeEmployee  extends  Employee{

    protected Float hourlyWage;

    public Float getHourlyWage() {
        return hourlyWage;
    }

    public void setHourlyWage(Float hourlyWage) {
        this.hourlyWage = hourlyWage;
    }
}
```

How could I avoid using instanceof when calling a method like this?

```
    public void convertEmployee(Employee employee) {

    if (employee instanceof FullTimeEmployee) {
       FullTimeEmployee fullTimeEmployee = (FullTimeEmployee) employee;
       calcSalaray(fullTimeEmployee);


    } else if (employee instanceof PartTimeEmployee) {
        PartTimeEmployee partTimeEmployee = (PartTimeEmployee) employee;
        calcHourlywage(partTimeEmployee);
    }

}
```

Comment: The code of the method should be replaced by... no code at all. It doesn't do anything. How could we advise a way to implement this method without knowing what it's supposed to do? Anyway, if you're aware of polymorphism, and of the visitor pattern, then you can implement whatever you want.

Comment: In general, one way would be to move the operation for each class into a method which is either implemented or defined as an abstract method on the Employee class. For some things, this wouldn't be advisable, but without knowing what operation you are trying to do, can't give an input in that regard

Comment: sorry for not providing more details. Let's assume we would like to do some calculations depending on the employee type. see edited question

Comment: This is still very vague. As it is described, you could simply add an abstract method `calculatePay()` in the base class, and override it in both subclasses (using the salary in one, and the hourly wage in the second). If the code can't be in the entity, and must invoke a method of the class containing `convertEmployee()`, then use the visitor pattern.

Comment: Thanks! I dont want to add that code to my entities. Could you provide a sample of the visitor pattern with my code?

Comment: @Codefella done. But it's the exact same visitor pattern, whether you have entities or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example using the visitor pattern. The fact that your classes are entities is irrelevant. What matters is that the base class has a fixed, well-known number of subclasses.

Let's start with the abstract class:

```
public abstract class Employee {
    public abstract void accept(EmployeeVisitor visitor);
}
```

It contains an accept() method taking a visitor as argument. Every subclass must override this method.

Now the two subclasses, each having a distinct set of fields and methods:

```
public class FrenchEmployee extends Employee {

    private int eiffelTowerVisits;

    @Override
    public void accept(EmployeeVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }

    public int getEiffelTowerVisits() {
        return eiffelTowerVisits;
    }
}


public class EnglishEmployee extends Employee {

    private int towerBridgeVisits;

    @Override
    public void accept(EmployeeVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }

    public int getTowerBridgeVisits() {
        return towerBridgeVisits;
    }
}
```

What is this visitor? It's an interface that does something specific for each subclass:

```
public interface EmployeeVisitor {
    void visit(EnglishEmployee employee);
    void visit(FrenchEmployee employee);
}
```

And here is an example of it usage, compared to the usage of instanceof:

```
public class EmployeeService {

    public void displayEmployeeWithUglyInstanceof(Employee employee) {
        if (employee instanceof EnglishEmployee) {
            EnglishEmployee english = (EnglishEmployee) employee;
            System.out.println("An English employee that visited the tower bridge " + english.getTowerBridgeVisits() + " times");
        }
        else if (employee instanceof FrenchEmployee) {
            FrenchEmployee french = (FrenchEmployee) employee;
            System.out.println("A French employee that visited the eiffel tower " + french.getEiffelTowerVisits() + " times");
        }
    }

    public void displayEmployeeWithVisitor(Employee employee) {
        EmployeeVisitor visitor = new EmployeeVisitor() {
            @Override
            public void visit(EnglishEmployee employee) {
                System.out.println("An English employee that visited the tower bridge " + employee.getTowerBridgeVisits() + " times");
            }

            @Override
            public void visit(FrenchEmployee employee) {
                System.out.println("A French employee that visited the eiffel tower " + employee.getEiffelTowerVisits() + " times");
            }
        };

        employee.accept(visitor);
    }
}
```

You might see that as overengineering, but in the case of Hibernate entities, it's actually very useful, because Hibernate uses dynamic proxies for lazy associations. So an employee might very well not be an EnglishEmployee nor a FrenchEmployee. In that case, `instanceof` will return false for both cases, and your code won't do anything. Whereas with the visitor, the proxy will delegate the call to the French or English employee it wraps, and everything will go smoothly.

Another advantage is that, if you add a SpanishEmployee, you will immediately see all the visitor implementations that must be modified to handle a spanish employee.

Answer (score 0):

One possible trick goes:

```
public abstract class Employee {
    // ...

    FullTimeEmployee asFullTimeEmployee() {
        return null;
    }

}

public class FullTimeEmployee extends Employee {

    // ...

    @override
    FullTimeEmployee asFullTimeEmployee() {
        return this;
    }

}
```